# Replacement Cipher

Tags: cryptography

Replacement cipher: Let τ be a permutation of the alphabet, and apply τ to each letter of the message. Frequency analysis is useful for breaking this type of code. Decode the following, which was encoded using a replacement cipher.

MIZVN KXXHA XRRTK NXYEX QIZVI IZXWM NXYGT JWVHC YTOXX QNHTI JYTWV NMHUR XOYLN ZTJTE XYAZX RWMHU XEMRK LIJYT WNWVR REXPV IMTHN OTHIM HLVRR GYXCX VIXQ --- NVWLX RBTZH NTH

I have made a frequency table of the occurrence of each letter in the above code.

X-18
T-12
H-10
N-10
R-10
I-9
V-9
Y-8
M-7
W-7
Z-6
E-4
J-4
L-4
K-3
O-3
Q-3
A-2
C-2
G-2
U-2
B-1
P-1
D-0
F-0
S-0

Comparing this with the frequency of letters occurring in English leads me to believe that X corresponds with E and that T corresponds with T. However this is where I get stuck.

Comment: Note that the words are in groups of five letters, except for the last words.  I don't know of any language with mostly five-letter words, so it seems that the spacings in between the words have been changed.  Also, it seems to be a quote.  The last three words is most likely the name of a person.

Comment: @Amzoti - using the frequencies in English, replacing letters based on that alone does not yield any clear text.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche - I saw that too; unfortunately that didn't help me when trying to replace letters.

Comment: Look at the double letters (XX, RR).  Do you know the frequencies of double letters in English?  (I expect EE, OO would be the highest).

Comment: This is problem 5.2 of *Survey of Mathematical Problems,* which is in English, so the text is also most likely in English.

Comment: Now asked at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5318/replacement-cipher

Comment: This is mixed alphabet or affine? Unfortunately for mixed alphabet, it can be tedious to decode without a large number of words(which you don't have above)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking to solve this yourself, but I have added the spoiler here as a check for when you have a final answer.  I will edit in some pointers if I get time soon.

> IT HAS BEEN WELL OBSERVED THAT THE MISERY OF MAN PROCEEDS NOT FROM A
>  SINGLE CRUSH OF OVER WHELMING EVIL BUT FROM SMALL VEXATIONS
>  CONTINUALLY REPEATED SAMUEL JOHNSON